# Symfony logical name confusion

Tags: symfony

So I am in the file: `src/Client/IntranetBundle/LDAP/LDAPAuthenticationProvider.php`

I want to call the method `getContainer` of `src/Client/IntranetBundle/ClientIntranetBundle.php`

So I am doing:

```
ClientIntranetBundle::getContainer();
```

But I am not using it correctly, because now I get the fatal error:

```
Class 'Client\IntranetBundle\LDAP\ClientIntranetBundle' not found
```

I need to go one level up in the folder hierarchy. How exactly do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the whole namespace when calling the class or add a `use` statement:

```
Client\IntranetBundle\ClientIntranetBundle::getContainer()
```

or at the beginning of the file (just under `namespace` declaration):

```
use Client\IntranetBundle\ClientIntranetBundle;
```

Comment: Yes, it works! It makes sense to add the namespace...Thank you.